# cdf for 'trimmed' normal distribution

Tags: python, scipy, normal-distribution

I have a left-censored normal distribution: it is 'flat' (equal to zero) up to `mu`, and then normal.

I know how to calculate cdf for a standard normal distribution:

```
from scipy.stats import norm
norm(mu, sigma).cdf(1)
```

for instance. But of course that is not correct for this 'truncated' version. Neither is correct:

```
norm(mu, sigma).cdf(1) - norm(mu, sigma).cdf(0)
```

because I should adjust values proportionally to the fact that the left tail is non-existent. What is the right way to do it?

Comment: Take a look at the [truncnorm](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.truncnorm.html) distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comment,

```
from scipy.stats import truncnorm
truncnorm(loc=1, scale=2, a=0, b=np.inf).cdf(x)
```

Where

- `loc` - mean
- `scale` - standard deviation
- `a` - left truncation point
- `b` - right truncation point
- `x` - evaluation point